# Finding the explicit formula for the succession $x_0=2, x_{n+1} = 5x_n$ and proving it with induction

Tags: recurrence-relations, induction

I'm trying to learn about recursion, first with this exercise:

> Find the explicit formula for the succession $$x_0=2, x_{n+1} = 5x_n$$

So, from what I've seen, I should test a bit. I see that the formula is pretty much the previous value by $5$:

$$x_0=2$$

$$x_1=5\cdot2$$

$$x_2=5\cdot(5\cdot 2)$$

$$x_3=5\cdot(5\cdot(5\cdot2))$$

It seems to me that a formula would be

$$x_n=5^n\cdot2$$

Now I have to prove it by induction, according to the exercise.

Test for $n=0$:

$$x_0 = 5^0\cdot2$$

$$2 = 2$$

I want to prove that it holds for $n + 1$, that is:

$$x_{n+1} = 5^{n+1}\cdot 2$$

Let's see:

$$x_{n+1}$$

This is where I'm getting a bit stuck, I had thought that the previous is equivalent to this:

$$x_n+5^{n+1}\cdot2$$

But that doesn't make any sense, because that would definitely be not equal to what I want to prove.

How should I had proceeded from this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to prove that $x_{n+1} = 5^{n+1} \cdot 2$. The induction hypothesis that you can use for this is $x_n = 5^n \cdot 2$. Now apply the recurrence relation and find $x_{n+1} = 5 x_n = 5 (5^n \cdot 2) = 5^{n+1} \cdot 2$.